# Abrir PDF en nueva ventana!

Tags: php

quisiera que me colaboraran, quiero que al momento de hacer la consulta al darle en el boton me manda a un reporte pdfm, lo que quiero es que no se me cierre la venta actual y se me abra el reporte en una nueva, este es mi codigo del formulario:

```
<form role="form" name="formulario" method="post" action="InformeReporteBeteitiva.php">
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 center-page">
      <div class="input-daterange input-group"  id="date-range">
        <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="start" id="start"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon bg-success text-white b-0">a</span>
        <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="end" id="end"/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success waves-effect w-md waves-light">Buscar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Y este este es el codigo del reporte pdf:

```
<?php


    include 'plantilla.php';
    require 'conexion.php';



        $query = "SELECT * FROM
            (
                SELECT Nombre, Cedula, sum(HorasTrabajo) as HorasTrabajo,sum(VC) as VC, sum(VR) as VR, sum(PA) as PA,
                       sum(PRG) as PRG, sum(PRI) as PRI, sum(TAC) as TAC, sum(TRM) as TRM, sum(MLC) as MLC, sum(BENDA) as BENDA, sum(EVS) as EVS,
                       sum(ADM) as ADM, sum(CRG) as CRG, sum(CDS) as CDS, sum(CNST) as CNST, sum(MTA) as MTA, sum(MTDCH) as MTDCH, sum(MTDPT) as MTDPT,
                       sum(Otros) as Otros   FROM reportebeteitiva
                                                  INNER JOIN trabajador ON reportebeteitiva.Trabajador = trabajador.idTrabajador
                                                  INNER JOIN centrocosto ON trabajador.CentroCosto = centrocosto.idCentroCosto
                                                  WHERE centrocosto.Estado = 'Activo' and trabajador.Estado = 'Activo' and Fecha BETWEEN '" . $_POST["start"] . "' AND '" . $_POST["end"] . "'

                                                  group by  Nombre, Cedula WITH ROLLUP
            )A WHERE ISNULL(Nombre) = ISNULL(Cedula)";

        $resultado = $mysqli->query($query);



        $pdf = new PDF();
        $pdf->AliasNbPages();
        $pdf->AddPage('L');


        $pdf->SetFillColor('232','232','232');
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B','10');
        $pdf->Cell(37,6,'NOMBRE',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(25,6,'CEDULA',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(16,6,'HORAS',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(10,6,'VC',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(10,6,'VR',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(10,6,'PA',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(10,6,'PRG',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(10,6,'PRI',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(10,6,'TAC',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(10,6,'TRM',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(10,6,'MLC',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(15,6,'BENDA',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(10,6,'EVS',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(10,6,'ADM',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(10,6,'CRG',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(10,6,'CDS',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(13,6,'CNST',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(10,6,'MTA',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(15,6,'MTDCH',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(15,6,'MTDPT',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(15,6,'OTROS',1,1,'C',1);

        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','','10');


        while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
        {

            $pdf->Cell(37,6,utf8_decode($row['Nombre']),1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(25,6,$row['Cedula'],1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(16,6,$row['HorasTrabajo'],1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(10,6,$row['VC'] ,1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(10,6,$row['VR'] ,1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(10,6,$row['PA'] ,1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(10,6,$row['PRG'] ,1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(10,6,$row['PRI'] ,1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(10,6,$row['TAC'] ,1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(10,6,$row['TRM'] ,1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(10,6,$row['MLC'] ,1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(15,6,$row['BENDA'] ,1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(10,6,$row['EVS'] ,1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(10,6,$row['ADM'] ,1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(10,6,$row['CRG'] ,1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(10,6,$row['CDS'] ,1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(13,6,$row['CNST'] ,1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(10,6,$row['MTA'] ,1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(15,6,$row['MTDCH'] ,1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(15,6,$row['MTDPT'] ,1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(15,6,$row['Otros'] ,1,1,'C');









        }
        $pdf->Output();








?>
```

Comment: quita button y agrega una etiqueta <a></a> y agregale el target _blank

Comment: Pero como logro mandar los 2 datos que necesito ??

Comment: <a class="btn btn-inverse" href="../../controllers/Caja/ImpTicket.php?numNota='.$notaNum.'" target="_blank"><i class="icon-print icon-white"></i> '.$notaNum.'</a>

Comment: Añadir en la etiqueta <form> el atributo target="_blank".

Answer (score 2):

con etiqueta `<a></a>` y un `target="_blank"`

por get pasas los parametros

```
<a class="btn btn-inverse" href="../../controllers/Caja/ImpTicket.php?numNota='.$notaNum.'" target="_blank"><i class="icon-print icon-white"></i> '.$notaNum.'</a>
```

Comment: Amigo gracias por la respuesta, pero como ve en mi codigo lo estoy enviando el datarange dos input que son 'start' y 'end', los cuales los recibe mi consulta en el archivo del reporte pdf en la consulta al final con el  `BETWEEN '" . $_POST["start"] . "' AND '" . $_POST["end"] . "'`

Answer (score 0):

Si esto lo haces desde el mismo formulario ( PHP con código HTML ) = InformeReporteBeteitiva.php es incorrecto, InformeReporteBeteitiva.php a de estar a parte del código del HTML, no puede estar en la misma página para que haga eso, ademas en ese código php tendras que volver a abrir la pagina original cuando hagas el SUBMIT o cuando cumplas con el objetivo en la pagina php que hace el pdf para que no pase eso. Perdona que no te ponga código pero son muchas cosas a rectificar...

Comment: Amigo solo necesito es que no me me redireccione con el metodo post, porque para el informe ya estoy usando un archivo que cree que es el informeBeteitiva